# How can create a button to link 2 frames in Java MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, jframe

Sorry, i have a trouble in MVC Java GUI. Because this one is very new for me.
1. How I can to create a frame when I clicked Run, it will show a frame with 2 buttons.
1 button is School to link this frame

[image: This is School Frame]

Another button is Teacher to link Teacher Frame

2. About Teacher Frame, will i create another discrete form in "view package" like JFTeacher or just create TeacherFrame in Other Components. Like this.
   (JFrame = School Frame)
   [image]

This is my Controller

```
 public class ControllerSchool implements ActionListener{


JFSchool viewSchool = new JFSchool();
SchoolDAO modelSchool = new SchoolDAO();

public ControllerSchool(JFSchool viewSchool, SchoolDAO modelSchool){
    this.modelSchool = modelSchool;
    this.viewSchool = viewSchool;
    this.viewSchool.btnadd.addActionListener(this);
    this.viewSchool.btndisplay.addActionListener(this);
}

public void InitializeSchool(){}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  if(e.getSource() ==viewSchool.btnadd){
      String scname = viewSchool.txtname.getText();
      String scadd = viewSchool.txtadd.getText();
      String scjobpos = viewSchool.txtjobpos.getText();
      String scjobexp = viewSchool.txtjobexp.getText();

String rptaRegister = modelSchool.insertSchool(scname, scadd, scjobpos, scjobexp);

if(rptaRegister!=null){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rptaRegister);
}else{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Add Error");}}

if (e.getSource()==viewSchool.btndisplay){
    LLenarTabla(viewSchool.tbdata);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Display records");
                                             }                                     }}
```

And this is my MVC Code

```
public class SchoolMVC {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFSchool viewC = new JFSchool();
    SchoolDAO modelC = new SchoolDAO();
    ControllerSchool controlC = new ControllerSchool(viewC, modelC);

    viewC.setVisible(true);
    viewC.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}}
```

Sorry for the long text, but I really do not know What is the best solution. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The best solution for your code is to have one JFrame with as many JPanels as you wish.  You can organize the JPanels with a JTabbedPane.  The [Oracle Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) might be the best solution for you to learn Swing.

Comment: I'd also recommend using a CardLayout